# Github: Can't upload file in folder, but can upload it in main repository

Tags: github

This is the first time I've tried uploading files to a folder in GitHub, and I seem to be having some issues.

I've made a folder: https://github.com/sam-mahdi/SAVUS/tree/master/Test_Files..
And I'm trying to upload files to it.

However, the files just don't seem to upload, it permanently says "`uploading 1 of 1 file`", but never does anything.

If I click commit, it tells me to upload something.
If I try to upload another file, it says "`Something went really wrong, and we can’t process that file.`", and I refresh the page.

The strange part is, I have no issue uploading multiple files (the same files) in the main repository, I only have this problem trying to upload it in the folder I made.
I've tried to close and open my browser. I am using chrome for reference (I saw online sometimes you get this issue if you use firefox).

Am I doing something wrong? or missing something?

Comment: There is not git “upload” command, so just what are we talking about here?

Comment: there is a button to upload files. From there you can then choose files to your repository

Comment: Weird. I had no idea. Since it’s a git repository, I always just use, uh, git. Might that be a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if possible, avoid '`..`' at the end of your [`TestFiles..` folder](https://github.com/sam-mahdi/SAVUS/tree/f2bf6ec949b24ed4d431fb484fc4d41e2145308a/Test_Files..).

Then try again uploading those files, to check if those trailing '`..`' were the issue.

Comment: Yes this worked, I didn't even notice the "..". Weird it broke the feature, but thank you!